# Pass an array variable to jq in bash

Tags: bash, jq

Is it possible to pass and use in jq a variable of type array?

```
jq --arg ips "${IPs[0]}" '.nodes.app.ip = $ips[0] | .nodes.data.ip = $ips[1]' nodes.json
```

Comment: You're showing an array of exactly two items. Is that degenerate case really all you want?

Comment: Also, do you need only the easy case where no array element can contain a literal newline?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy of course not, it’s just for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *general case* solution is to pass that array in on stdin with NUL delimiters:

```
IPs=( 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 )
original_doc='{"nodes": { "app": {}, "data": {} }}'

jq -Rn --argjson original_doc "$original_doc" '
  input | split("\u0000") as $ips
  | $original_doc
  | .nodes.app.ip = $ips[0]
  | .nodes.data.ip = $ips[1]
' < <(printf '%s\0' "${IPs[@]}")
```

...emits as output:

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "app": {
      "ip": "1.2.3.4"
    },
    "data": {
      "ip": "5.6.7.8"
    }
  }
}
```

This is overkill for an array of IP addresses, but it works in the general case, even for actively-hostile arrays (ones with literal quotes, literal newlines, and other data that's intentionally hard-to-parse).

---

If you want to keep stdin clean, you can use a second copy of `jq` to convert your array to JSON:

```
IPs=( 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 )
IPs_json=$(jq -Rns 'input | split("\u0000")' < <(printf '%s\0' "${IPs[@]}"))

jq --argjson ips "$IPs_json" '
    .nodes.app.ip = $ips[0]
  | .nodes.data.ip = $ips[1]
' <<<'{"nodes": { "app": {}, "data": {} }}'
```

Comment: Its working locally, but when I'm sending it via ssh jq doesn't work properly...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428131/sending-jq-with-argjson-via-ssh